# Is it possible to get a @font-face html entity into an input via javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text input: `<input type="text">` and I have a Icomoon @font-face font setup that has some symbols that I'd ideally like to get into the input via some buttons that a user clicks.

My font-face font has options to use an **HTML entity**, for example:

```
&#xe601;
```

My javascript makes an array of data-attributes values which i then map to hex values, such as this heart symbol *(note I think im correct in calling it a hex value)*:

```
\u2665
```

So is there a way I can get this working. Or will I need to re-think my approach. Placing the HTML entity directly into my HTML shows the icon works, I'm guessing how it's being placed in via settings the `.val();` in the input it causing issues.

```js
$('.char__item-indv').click(function(event) {

  var word = $(this).attr('data-value'),
      input_word = $('#wordSelector').val(),
      input_start_word = $('#wordSelector')[0].defaultValue,
      char_array = new Array();

  char_array['and'] = '&';
  char_array['apo'] = '\x27';
  char_array['at'] = '@';
  char_array['bee'] = '&#xe601;';
  char_array['dot'] = '.';
  char_array['heart'] = '\u2665';
  char_array['the'] = '&#58881;';

  if(input_word == input_start_word) {
    input_word = '';
  }

  if(input_word.length < 12) {
    var new_word = input_word+char_array[word];
    $('#wordSelector').val(new_word);
    $(this).prop("selectedIndex",0);
    $('#wordSelector').focus();
  }

});
```

```css
.word-selector__input {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.word-selector__char {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.word-selector .char__item {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="word-selector">

  <div class="word-selector__input">
    <input name="input-word" type="text" maxlength="12" id="wordSelector" />
  </div>

  <div class="word-selector__char">
    <div class="char__item">
      <img class="char__item-indv" alt="AND" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" data-value="and" />
    </div>
    <div class="char__item">
      <img class="char__item-indv" alt="Apostrophe" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" data-value="apo" />
    </div>
    <div class="char__item">
      <img class="char__item-indv" alt="@" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" data-value="at" />
    </div>
    <div class="char__item">
      <img class="char__item-indv" alt="Bee" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" data-value="bee" />
    </div>
    <div class="char__item">
      <img class="char__item-indv" alt="Dot" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" data-value="dot" />
    </div>
    <div class="char__item">
      <img class="char__item-indv" alt="Heart" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" data-value="heart" />
    </div>
    <div class="char__item">
      <img class="char__item-indv" alt="The" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" data-value="the" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="word-selector__submitter">
    <input type="submit" name="Btn1" value="Go" onclick="" id="Btn1" />
  </div>

</div>
```

**To make things easier I've made a working example:** http://codepen.io/vdecree/pen/QwOvaX

Comment: Does doing something like `var text = $("<div/>").html(char_array[word]).text(); var new_word = input_word + text;`  work?

Comment: That does indeed seem to work. Do you want to post that as an answer so it can be accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let html do the hard work of converting it:

```
var text = $("<div/>").html(char_array[word]).text();
var new_word = input_word + text;
```

---

```js
$('.char__item-indv').click(function(event) {

  var word = $(this).attr('data-value'),
      input_word = $('#wordSelector').val(),
      input_start_word = $('#wordSelector')[0].defaultValue,
      char_array = new Array();

  char_array['and'] = '&';
  char_array['apo'] = '\x27';
  char_array['at'] = '@';
  char_array['bee'] = '&#xe601;';
  char_array['dot'] = '.';
  char_array['heart'] = '\u2665';
  char_array['the'] = '&#58881;';

  if(input_word == input_start_word) {
    input_word = '';
  }

  if(input_word.length < 12) {
    var text = $("<div/>").html(char_array[word]).text();
    var new_word = input_word + text;
    $('#wordSelector').val(new_word);
    $(this).prop("selectedIndex",0);
    $('#wordSelector').focus();
  }

});
```

```css
.word-selector__input {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.word-selector__char {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.word-selector .char__item {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="word-selector">

  <div class="word-selector__input">
    <input name="input-word" type="text" maxlength="12" id="wordSelector" />
  </div>

  <div class="word-selector__char">
    <div class="char__item">
      <img class="char__item-indv" alt="AND" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" data-value="and" />
    </div>
    <div class="char__item">
      <img class="char__item-indv" alt="Apostrophe" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" data-value="apo" />
    </div>
    <div class="char__item">
      <img class="char__item-indv" alt="@" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" data-value="at" />
    </div>
    <div class="char__item">
      <img class="char__item-indv" alt="Bee" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" data-value="bee" />
    </div>
    <div class="char__item">
      <img class="char__item-indv" alt="Dot" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" data-value="dot" />
    </div>
    <div class="char__item">
      <img class="char__item-indv" alt="Heart" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" data-value="heart" />
    </div>
    <div class="char__item">
      <img class="char__item-indv" alt="The" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" data-value="the" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="word-selector__submitter">
    <input type="submit" name="Btn1" value="Go" onclick="" id="Btn1" />
  </div>

</div>
```